# xmllint: Formating without adding header

Tags: bash, xmllint

Is there a way to use `$xmllint --format file` without the header section?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tag>
  <Sub>A</Sub>
</Tag>
```

I know you can use `--c14n` but that does not seem to mix well with `--format`.
As `$xmllint --format --c14n file` will just produce:

```
<Tag><Sub>A</Sub></Tag>
```

**Desired Result**

```
<Tag>
  <Sub>A</Sub>
</Tag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed to remove the first line. Not saying it's the best but it would get you going:

```
xmllint --format <file> | sed 1d
```

You would preferrable try to avoid one million calls to `xmllint`. And sed or tail.

I'm not sure if `xmllint` supports inplace edit. But if it does then something like this might be possible:

```
xargs < list_of_files_to_change.txt xmllint --inplace --format
xargs < list_of_files_to_change.txt sed -i 1d
```

Comment: I probably should have added to the request that the script will run for about 1M individual files. Would sed be more optimal than tail -n +2?. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @Overseer10 I'm not sure, I updated the answer with more information.

Comment: From my measurements on a Mac `sed 1d` is 10-15x faster than `tail -n +2`

Comment: Unfortunately, xmllint has no in-place option. Maybe we could show an example with a `while` loop using `sponge` (moreutils) or a temporal file?